# Using string literals to get object property with Typescript

Tags: typescript

Fairly new to using Typescript, so forgive if there's a prior example to what my question that I've seen but not understood. I'm trying to **dynamically find the key of an object** in a way that avoids using conditionals to determine which property to get.

Here is an example of the code:

```js
public buildUrl(appName: string, itemNumber: string) {
  const url: EnvEndpoint = obj[`prefix${appName}`]
  return `${url[process.env.NODE_ENV]}/endpoint/${itemNumber.toString()}`
}
```

The key that I want to be dynamic is, which I get an error of the key could be `any` and is rejected.

```
obj[`prefix${appName}`]
```

---

*For further context if at all needed.*

The `EnvEndpoint` is an imported interface that looks like this:

```js
export interface EnvEndpoint {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

The `obj` being imported pulls data that looks like this as an example:

```json
"key": {
  "dev": "https://www.google.dev",
  "qa": "https://www.google.qa",
  "uat": "https://www.google.uat",
  "prod": "https://www.google.com",
}
```

Comment: I did not understand. Which one are you trying dynamically find the key of an object of ? Are you looking for `keyof` ?

Comment: @ShyamPillai thanks for the call out, I updated it.

Comment: OK but where's the type/interface of `obj`? Is it inferred from somewhere maybe? That's what you need to change. `(obj as any)[`prefix${appName}`]` would most certainly work.

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: @ShyamPillai want to make your comment a non-sub comment so one so I can make as answered!